# TexMaker No Longer Compiling On High Sierra

Tags: compiling, texmaker

As with others, I encountered issues compiling PDFs when I updated my OS to El Capitan. I followed the directions listed on the TexMaker website for changing /usr/texbin paths to /Library/Tex/texbin and it worked like a charm. Then, I upgraded my OS to High Sierra and TexMaker stopped compiling PDFs. Once again, I followed the directions listed on the TexMaker website and changed all of the /usr/texbin paths to /Library/Tex/texbin. Unfortunately, that did not work this time. I've triple-checked for typos in the paths and found none.

I also removed all documents except the .tex file from the folder and clicked on the "Quick Build" button to see what would happen. I received a "Could not start the command" error message.

Please help. Why is TexMaker suddenly failing to compile my PDFs?

Comment: Should tat be /Library/TeX/texbin (I.e., TeX rather than TeX)? What does the command `which pdflatex` return when run in Terminal.app?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Yes, sorry for the typo! I have replaced the /usr/texbin with /Library/TeX/texbin--TeX, not Tex. Regarding your second question, could you please elaborate? What do you mean by when run in Terminal.app? Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: The Terminal application is found in the Utilities folder in the Application folder. After starting up the Terminal application enter `which pdflatex` and press return. Let us know what it then says.